# a bit of confusion over pointers (void ones) and functions

Tags: c++, pointers, bit-manipulation, void

so right now i am trying to do some nift code for a little game i am making and I've run into something that has been bothering me for a while about pointers.

but first things first, i am trying to have a function take in a void* and give that void* a value, but it seems to not actually stay beyond the function like i'm used to. so...

```
void ItemGen(void* Holder){

    Item* NewItem
    NewItem = new Item*
    NewItem->Init();
    Holder = NewItem;

}
```

it's not actually making "items" but various kinds of items that inherit from a item, this is just me making it simpler.

Holder gets changed but never make it outside the function, how should i change this, so that it does.

on top of that, i am sort of confused about a certain occurrence that can happen and i just want to know what happens when you do these. or really the difference between them

```
void *p1;
void *p2;
&p1 = &p2;
p1 = p2;
*p1 = *p2;
```

oh and is there a way to do a XOR operation on pointers so i can swap them with out a holding pointer.

i feel like i asked very stupid questions, but are confusing simply because they're void *'s.

Comment: Also, there are many immediate syntax problems in your code. Missing semicolons, type-incorrect assignments (`NewItem = new Item*`). Why not try compile some of this and work your way through the error messages before posting.

Comment: There are 3 great hurdles when learning to program: flow control (loops, recursion, and functions), indirection (references and pointers), and concurrency (threads, processes, and synchronization).  Welcome to hurdle 2.  I hope you passed 1 already.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are variables like any other, and as such are passed by value to functions.  You've simply assigned a new value to the parameter copy of your pointer.

If you want to change a variable you pass to a function you must pass by reference or by pointer.  Preferably the former.

```
void ItemGen(void *& Holder);
```

BTW, that's a horrible naming convention.

Comment: my c is a bit rusty but cant you remove both the * and &? seems silly

Comment: hmm i also though *& cancels each other out, which made me thing i wouldn't work. also, yes, horrible horrible names, good thing i'm not actually using those.

Comment: @Jake & user - C++ is not C.  Different language, different operators, different rules.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this point "Holder gets changed but never make it outside the function, how should i change this, so that it does."

```
void ItemGen(Item** Holder){
 Item* NewItem
 NewItem = new Item*
 NewItem->Init();
 *Holder = NewItem;
}

void someotherfunc() {
 Holder * holder=0;
 ItemGen(&holder)
 if(holder!=0) {
      holder->dosomething()
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"void" simply means "nothing". A "void*" pointer points to nothing in particular. It's a way of saying "I don't know what kind of thing this pointer points to"; a void* pointer is a catch all that can *receive* any kind of pointer, but if you want to go from a void* pointer to any other kind, you have to explicitly cast it.

As to your first problem:

If you lived at "1234 Pointer Street", there is nothing magical about the number "1234", it's just a number. It only tells you anything when you treat it as a "pointer" - a house number. It "points" to a house on a particular street.

In the case of a computer, the street is memory.

```
int a = 0;
int* b = 0;
```

the variables "a" and "b" both contain the numeric value "0".

```
b = b + 1;
```

See? perfectly valid. So

```
void foo(int a, int* b)
{
    a = a + 1;
    b = b + 1;
}

void bar()
{
    int x = 0;
    int* y = 0;
    foo(x, y);
    // 'x' and 'y' are still zero here, they have to be, or you couldn't do
    foo(0, 0);
}
```

Pointers to have some distinguishing features from regular variables.

```
int a = 0;
int* b = 0;

a = a + 1; // now a = 1
b = b + 1; // now b = b + sizeof(int) => 4.
```

What pointers do best is provide values for C/C++'s "dereference" operators.

```
a = *(b);
```

Going back to the streets example, if we assigned b our "1234 Pointer Street" address, it would be:

```
b = 1234;
```

What if we wanted to deliver something there?

```
*b
```

This means: The contents of the address that b describes.

Lets go back to the definition

```
int* b;
```

This says: "b is the address of an integer". How do we get the address of a specific integer?

```
// imagine a set of mailboxes.
int box1, box2, box3, box4, box5;

// lets put something interesting into box 3.
box3 = 5;

// now let's address somethign to box3.
// "&" is the "address of" operator.
int* pointer = &box3;

// now lets put something more interesting in pointer.
pointer = 10;
// whoops - that was wrong, we just changed the ADDRESS to some random numeric value.
// what we mean't was:
*pointer = 10;

printf("box 3 contains %d\n", box3);
// answer? 10, not 5.
```

After setting "pointer = &box3" we populated "pointer" with the location of box3's storage in memory, so when we wrote to that address using "*pointer = 10" we wrote to the storage address of box3.

You asked about
    void *p1;
    void *p2;
    &p1 = &p2;
    p1 = p2;
    *p1 = *p2;

"&p1 = &p2" says "the address of p1 is the address of p2" and isn't legal, it wouldn't compile.

"p1 = p2" is legal, but it says "assign the same address as p2 to p1"

"*p1 = *p2" is illegal because you are using void pointers, which point to void, besides, you've just made p1 and p2 be equal to each other so it would be a null operation.

To fix your initial problem, you would need to provide a way for the caller to receive the new value you are creating.

Option 1: Accept a pointer-to-pointer

This is the very old-school C way to do it, but your code doesn't look very C++ so far so I'll list it first.

```
void ItemGen(void** Holder)
{
    Item* NewItem = new Item;
    NewItem->Init(); // why doesn't the constructor do this?
    // ** means pointer to storage that is itself also a pointer,
    // so if we dereference it once we will be refering to the inner pointer.
    *Holder = NewItem; 
}
```

Option 2: Return a pointer

```
void* ItemGen() // Why isn't this "Item*"?
{
    Item* NewItem = new Item;
    NewItem->Init();
    return NewItem;
}
```

Option 3: Take a reference

```
void ItemGen(Item*& Holder)
{
    Holder = new Item;
    Holder->Init();
}
```

This says "Holder is a reference to a pointer to storage of type Item". It's exactly like a "Item*" pointer except instead of creating a temporary local copy of the value passed in, it's an *alias* for the value that was passed in.

If you absolutely have to throw away the type information of your pointer:

```
void ItemGen(void*& Holder)
{
    Item* NewItem = new Item;
    NewItem->Init();
    Holder = NewItem;
}
```

At the level you appear to be with C++ so far, I would guess that your use of void* pointers is probably misguided.